# Get first paragraph in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a problem with getting the first

form the_excerpt();

Function acutally works but only for first post. I added in functions.php

```
function get_first_paragraph(){
global $post;

$str = wpautop( get_the_content() );
$str = substr( $str, 0, strpos( $str, '</p>' ) + 4 );
$str = strip_tags($str, '<a><strong><em>');
return '<p>' . $str . '</p>';
}
```

I'm calling this funcion in index.php inside The Loop `<?php echo get_first_paragraph(); ?>`

I have no idea why it pulls only for first post...

Comment: you can call this function using with hook

Comment: and how is that ?

Comment: Check the answer post

Answer (score 1):

you can put this code in function.php file in your theme,

**Get first paragraph**

```html
function awesome_excerpt($text, $raw_excerpt) {
    if( ! $raw_excerpt ) {
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        $text = substr( $content, 0, strpos( $content, '</p>' ) + 4 );
    }    
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'awesome_excerpt', 10, 2 );
```

For more information, you can follow the reference link [WORDPRESS THE_EXCERPT SHOW ONLY FIRST PARAGRAPH](https://www.bybe.net/wordpress-the_excerpt-show-first-paragraph/)

Comment: I've read this post but this code gives me this `Fatal error
: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function awesome_excerpt()`

Comment: i call it by `<?php echo awesome_excerpt(); ?>` but what is `$text and $raw_excerpt` ?

Comment: $text and $raw_excerpt is a parameters. It define text characters. like $text = 10 and $raw_excerpt = 2

Comment: i get this working but still i get only first post with this description. Here is my Loop http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f8f728a3205d460fb67647d4838559bc00d63a96

Answer (score 0):

That code didn't work for me in Gutenberg times. So I've used part of that code and did some searching and come up with this solution. Hope it helps.

```
function get_paragraph_content($paragraph_number){
    global $post;
    $i = 0;
    $paragraph = '';
    if ( has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
        $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
        foreach( $blocks as $block ) {
            if( 'core/paragraph' === $block['blockName']){
                $paragraph = render_block($block);                
                if (++$i == $paragraph_number) break;
            }
        }
        $paragraph = substr( $paragraph, 0, strpos( $paragraph, '</p>' ) + 4 );
        $paragraph = strip_tags($paragraph, '<a><strong><em>');        
    }
    return $paragraph;
}
```